# Pymongo, which of these aggregare query will perform better

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have pasted here two pymongo aggregate queries, both will return the same result.
I want to know, which one will perform better,

**conditions in two match pipeline**

```
db.bseadjprice.aggregate([
            {"$match":{"scripcode":"533159"}} ,
            {"$match":{"date":{"$in":dt}}}, 
            {"$project":{"_id":0, "high":"$high", "low" : "$low"}}
        ])
```

**conditions in single match pipeline**

```
db.bseadjprice.aggregate([
        {"$match":{"scripcode":"533159", "date": {"$in":dt}}}, 
        {"$project":{"_id":0, "high":"$high", "low" : "$low"}}
    ])
```

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Have you tried using $explain (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/explain/) to see what it's doing? You didn't mention what's indexed. The best answer would come from doing real tests. Why not use just `find` instead of `aggregate`?

Comment: No, I have not tried $explain. Thanks. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Why are you using `aggregate` rather than just `find`?

Answer (score 0):

Two matches could prevent 1 event:
If first match false - second match wont do work. it could be faster in cycles or with big data and strong query.